# Can Raider Attacks occur while you are not in the game?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I have some soldier class dwellers that have great weapons and stats, but I could obviously use them in other rooms.

But if attacks can occur while I'm not in the game, I need them to be at the Vault Door to ward off attackers.

So I'm curious if anyone knows if attacks can happen while you're not there.

Thanks!

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but solves your problem: Go ahead and try to use those soldiers in another room anyway. My guards are working at the cafeteria (which I have placed just right from the ground floor elevator next to the vault door) all the time, and raiders always come there first. It is even more efficient, because it is a triple room, hosting six armed guards, while the vault door can only have four.

Never underestimate the tenacity of the post-apocalyptic waiters and waitresses. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, raider attacks can not occur while you do not have the app in the foreground.

No incidents occur while the app is closed. Only three things can happen while in the background:

1. Resources will continue to be consumed for a short while after moving to the background
2. Timers for production, child birth, and S.P.E.C.I.A.L. leveling will run to completion.
3. Wasteland explorers keep on exploring (and looting and getting damage).

Comment: I added that also explorers keep on exploring, which is actually very important to keep in mind, so that they don't run out of stimpaks and die.

Answer (score 0):

Thing is, you might not be able to tell. The resources may go down a bit, but that happens anyway with normal consumption. I think the only indication would be if a dweller dies. And even that's iffy, if you already have dwellers with low health and you don't have enough food/water.

Answer (score 0):

Raiders have not attacked for me. No one is dead although I have a cabin next to the vault door. However, explorers will explore and gather loot, and resources will be consumed for a while. I'ld suggest going to the main menu before quitting the app. To go to the main menu, use the pip boy and tap the settings.

Answer (score 0):

Closing the application during a raider attack accidentally may cause some casualties (I am not 100% sure how that works) but then again raiders are the least annoying hazard.

Guards 2 Lunch box rare or legendary weapon above 12 damage or (1) 12+ and another weapon 5+ damage all dead. one might get lucky and run into another room but a couple more shots from anyone else they will die doing minor damages.

It doesn't matter if you have level 1 common dwellers guarding you against the pesky raiders. Stimpacks are easy to make max out my storage easily enough might need 4 max per invasion if you use level 1s with bad stats.

Answer (score -1):

Raider Attacks can happen at anytime in Fallout Shelter, even when the app isn't open.

Some ways to protect your vault is by having dwellers guard the vault door and by upgrading your vault door. When you upgrade the vault door, it increases its health and decreases the chances of an attack.

Comment: You are the only one to say this so far. I have not had one event happen while I was not in the game, been playing since launch.

Comment: I would recommend more observation here.  Neither I nor any of my friends have seen any proof of this happening.

Comment: Well actually, I haven't had a raider attack occur with the game until not that long ago (20-30 mins ago). It's just not that common.

Comment: I just realized I typed my comment wrong, oops! I meant that I haven't had any raider attacks with the app closed until not that long ago; and don't forget that they aren't that common.

Comment: I have now player for three days. I have warded off tens of raider attacks, if not even over hundred. And not a single one when the app was on the background, including two nights and one day at work. How does the game even inform you that an attack has happened?

My alternate theory is that the attack started just a tad before you switched app, and hence was left to be resolved anyway on the background.

(I actually tried to find out what happens when you switch app when the raiders are attacking. I might have to find out that myself.)

Comment: Yeah, I have been playing for days at this point and not one time has an "incident" of any kind occurred while I'm not in the app.

Comment: Also I have read about some bug reports that the game hasn't suspended it properly on the background, but instead kept on running, and running out of resources. If that's the reason, the same bug might as well give some raider attacks on the background. Just pondering for other explanations.

Comment: @synchronos That possibly could be the reason. Maybe Raider Attacks outside of the game were not intended, but this bug changes that.

Comment: I'm still waiting on a raider attack when I am not on the game btw....yet to happen....how do I know? unarmed people in the closest rooms to the entrance. The raiders go room to room in order, no one is dead...

Comment: Incidents cannot happen while the game is not running, but if the game is saved during attack, it gets suspended and continues only after you load it again.